# How to subset by additional condition in same column

Tags: r

I'm going through some subsetting examples with mtcars, like here:

```
mtcars[mtcars$gear == 5, ]
```

now this returns me all the rows in mtcars where `gear = 5`, but how do I tell it for example to also return the rows where `gear = 4` as well?

I have been looking at logical operators and such, but neither & nor | seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `%in%` instead of `==`

```
mtcars[mtcars$gear %in%  c(4, 5), ]
```

Comment: thank you very much.
what would be the advantage of using `%in%` over `==`?

Comment: @Leovar the difference is that `==` is elementwise comparison.  It is mostly to compare objects of same length or dimensions.  If the length of the object is 1 on the rhs, it just recycles to do the comparison on all other elements on the rhs.  If the length is greater than 1 and not equal to the lhs object length, the recycling kicks on.  So, in your case, on every 2 elements of the 'gear', the 4, 5 is getting compared i.e. 1 and 2 elements to values 4, 5, then 3 and 4 to 4, 5, etc..

Comment: alright, I see. in that case `%in%` really does work better for my intends and purposes.
Many thanks!